# Dynamic horizontal node/tree structure in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I am trying to implement a horizontal tree structure in one project. I have done it in my previous project but not able to implement the same feature in Angular 6.

[image]

I want to create above structure dynamically/at runtime using Angular.

Comment: Have a look at inbuild tree structure available in the NG 6 here is official document :https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples

Comment: *I have done it in my previous project but not able to implement the same feature in Angular 6.*??? Kindly Mention what did you try so far ?what did not work and provide some code for reference?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I have seen those examples..And I want same structure which is shown in image...

Comment: Ok then you have to write some code with the help of the internet! or if you have already then paste it here

Comment: @Vikas I have done same structure through HTML/javascript... & I don't find same  horizantal tree structure in angular material

Comment: I would suggest there are some third parties library who provides the tree structure UI so jst find out who fits in your requirement

Answer (score 1):

The ngx-org-chart creates hierarchical organization chart. You can create hierarchical organization charts with it.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-org-chart

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31404800)